# R: cropping/zooming a map

Tags: r, plot, ggmap

I am trying to overlay data on top of a map of Canada, however I can't adjust the zoom as I would like. In the map, I want to be able to see the lines for each province anong with its name (so using map("world", "Canada") isn't desirable)

I have tried altering the zoom, but one is too zoomed out and the other is too zoomed in:

```
qmap(location = "Canada", zoom = 3)
```

[image]

```
qmap(location = "Canada", zoom = 4)
```

[image]

I have tried researching on how to crop the image but have been unsuccessful

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use `ggmap` to create this map? Also, what is the spatial range of your data? Having an entire map of Canada may not be suitable if the data are concentrated to one area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this using either the `maps` and `mapsdata` packages or continue with `ggmap`. It just depends on how much detail you want.

```
library(raster)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
canada<-getData("GADM",country="CAN",level=1)

plot(canada,xlim=c(-141,-53),ylim=c(40,85),col="gray80",border="gray40",axes=T,las=1)
invisible(text(getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots(canada),labels=as.character(substr(canada$HASC_1,4,5)), 
               cex=0.75, col="black",font=2))
```

[image]

Using `ggmap`, you can specify a bounding box when grabbing your spatial data. It still overplots some of the area you are interested in (i.e., plots most of the US). Therefore, reapplying the bounding box values to the `ggmap` function cuts down the viewable area.

```
library(ggmap)

lats<-c(40,85)
lons<-c(-141,-53)
bb<-make_bbox(lon=lons,lat=lats,f=0.05)
cda<-get_map(bb,zoom=3,maptype="terrain")
ggmap(cda)+xlim(lons)+ylim(lats)+theme_bw()+labs(x="Longitude",y="Latitude")
```

[image]